# Find if an element is the product of all the other elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function that return true if one of the element is the product of all the other elements (itself excluded).

For exemple:

```
const isThereAProduct([2, 8, 4, 1]) // output : true
// (Because 8 = 2 x 4 x 1)
```

So far I have the solution

```js
function canPartition(array) {
    let productArray = array.reduce((acc, val) => acc * val)
    let isThereOne = false
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == productArray / array[i]) {
            isThereOne = true
            return isThereOne
        }
    }

}

console.log(canPartition([1, 2, 3, 4, 24]))
```

But my function doesn't work if array[i] = 0 because it will divide the product by itself (0) and it becomes NaN of course.

So maybe I want to add

```
if (array[i] == 0 && productArray == 0) {
    isThereOne = true
    return isThereOne
}
```

But then I will have to do also if array[i] == 0 && productArray !== 0 but it's impossible *lol*.

**Will appreciate some help on that one guys :)**

Comment: I have splice(0,1) in my mind but don't know exactly how to use it for this problem

Comment: `array[i] *array[i]  == productArray` just bit of algebra lol

Comment: Of topic: Why do you have a variable `isThereOne`? You assign it twice, but never use it. You could just `return true` in your if statement body and `return false` at the end of your function body.

Comment: `if (array[i] == productArray / array[i])` is equivalent to `if (array[i] * array[i]  == productArray)`. That is what Abishek Kumar meant. This way you can avoid the division by 0

Comment: lol feel stupid rn

Comment: But you still have to add a special case for `0`, e.g.  for [0, 1, 2, 3] the condition `if (array[0] * array[0]  == productArray)` will be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a special case for zeros:

```
function canPartition(array) {
    let productArray = array.reduce((acc, val) => acc * val);
    if (productArray === 0) return array.filter(x => x === 0).length > 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == productArray / array[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(canPartition([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 24]))
```

Comment: I love the return arr.count(0) > 1 ! Just checking if it pass some tests

Comment: @YoëlZerbib Sadly there is no count in JavaScript. That was a mistake.

Comment: I was writing this with a js equivalent also

Answer (score 1):

There is just one case that you will get `true` and it is the time that the `array` contains two elements with `0`. so just check this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
console.log(canPartition([1,2,4,8,1]))

function canPartition(arr) {
  product = 1
  maxPos = Math.max(...arr)
  maxNeg = Math.min(...arr)
  if ((maxNeg *= -1) > maxPos) {
    max = maxNeg
  } else {
    max = maxPos
  }
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(max),1)
  for (let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    product *= arr[i]
  }
  if (product == max) {
    ans = true
  } else {
    ans = false
  }
  count = 0;
  for (let i =0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 0) count++
  }
  if (count == 1) {
    ans = false
  } else if (count >= 2) {
    ans = true
  }
  return ans
}
```

Comment: it returns false with that input?, if there is a zero the product is going to be zero no matter what so it should return false

Comment: Yes, it returns false, but it should return true, because 0 === 0 * 4 * 8 * 1

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, let me try and fix that

Comment: This is fixed, if product is zero there must be a zero in the array so can just return true

Comment: But if product is zero and there is only one zero it should return false

Comment: fixed, all be it not very elegant

Comment: But you reduced it to positive integers. Does it work with [-1, -8, 2, 4]?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Using [.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method of native javascript array

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function create a new array filtered by condition

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

And reduce, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array, and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

```js
    const canPartition = (array) => {
          // return true if one of return is true
          return array.some((val, it, self) => {
             // is current value equal the product of numbers except the current
             return val == self.filter((f,id) => id!=it ).reduce((a,b) => a*b);
          });
        }
    console.log(canPartition([1, 2, 3, 4, 24]));
    console.log(canPartition([0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 24]));
```

Comment: Wow this went hard can you provide pseudocode to explain what it does ? I see the point with the reduce but what are we filtering ? Self seems to be the array itself ? it the index and val the current value ?

Comment: @YoëlZerbib reduce is a array native javascript function this is the complete and official documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce, filter is filtering from an array by a condition https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter .

Answer (score 0):

```
const isThereAProduct = (array) => 
    array.some((e,idx,arr) => e === arr.concat().fill(1,idx,idx+1)
    .reduce((acc,e) => 
    Math.imul(acc,e)) )
```

i think this will work but it involve making intermediate array.